# didEnterRegion only gets fired sometimes

Tags: swift, callback, ibeacon

I wrote the code below, which is the most basic Swift 3 code I could think of in order to check if my app can detect if an iBeacon is available.
However, the didEnterRegion is only fired up once in a blue moon. I probably ran it on my phone 20 times, and it only got fired twice. The problem does not seem to be the beacon itself, as when I use an app from the App store, it always detects my iBeacon. Any ideas why this callback is rarely called?
PS: I have already added Privacy - Location Always Usage Description to Info.plist

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func startMonitoring(_ sender: Any) {
    if let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "10F86430-1346-11E4-9191-0800200C9A66") {
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 1, minor: 1,identifier: "iBeacon")
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        textLabel.text = "Monitoring"
    }
}
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, monitoringDidFailFor region: CLRegion?, withError error: Error) {
    textLabel.text = "\(error.localizedDescription)"
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    textLabel.text = "\(error.localizedDescription)"
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        textLabel.text = "Found a new beacon"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to exit the region, wait 30 secs or so and enter again to have it trigger. If you are staying in the region it won't trigger.

Comment: This is the most likely explanation.